# magento-check.php on XAMPP

Tags: installation

I am trying to get Magento to work on XAMPP, I currently use the newest version of XAMPP, I have followed the guidelines for XAMPP installation which can be found here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/installing_on_windows_with_xampp_and_wamp

But when I run the magento-check.php to see if everything would work, I get this really weird output that is partly an output and partly php code...

I get this:

```
You need PHP 5.2.0 (or greater)'; } else { $pass .='
You have PHP 5.2.0 (or greater)
'; } if(!ini_get('safe_mode')) { $pass .='
Safe Mode is off
'; preg_match('/[0-9]\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/', shell_exec('mysql -V'), $version); if(version_compare($version[0], '4.1.20', '<')) { $fail .= '
You need MySQL 4.1.20 (or greater)
'; } else { $pass .='
You have MySQL 4.1.20 (or greater)
'; } } else { $fail .= '
Safe Mode is on
'; } foreach($extensions as $extension) { if(!extension_loaded($extension)) { $fail .= '
You are missing the '.$extension.' extension
'; } else{ $pass .= '
You have the '.$extension.' extension
'; } } if($fail) { echo '

Your server does not meet the following requirements in order to install Magento.'; echo '
The following requirements failed, please contact your hosting provider in order to receive assistance with meeting the system requirements for Magento:'; echo '

'.$fail.'

'; echo 'The following requirements were successfully met:'; echo '

'.$pass.'

'; } else { echo '

Congratulations! Your server meets the requirements for Magento.
'; echo '

'.$pass.'

'; } } ?>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Check if short tags are allowed in your PHP config, that might be the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You get this strange output because you don't have short tags enabled on your server and the `magento-check.php` file starts with `<?`.
Change that first line to `<?php` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the required settings for magento is not matched the version you have installed with xampp.

Magento needs higher version of php and mysql which is clearly shown in the error.

Try to install the new version of xampp which has these version of php and mysql

Comment: I have installed the newest version of XAMPP, I downloaded it from their website yesterday.

Comment: running phpinfo(); gives me PHP Version 5.5.11

Comment: the newest version of xampp has php 5.5.11 and mysql 5.6.16

Comment: And I do have that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it means that your web server is not passing your .php files to PHP to interpret. It's probably configuration issue, php has been turned off or something similar.